# terraform -refresh-only command not working

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm-template, azure-rm, hashicorp

I am new to terraform and would be helpful if anyone can look into this issue.
My issue is tried creating my infrastructure resource via terraform and made few changes outside terraform, then included them in my code. However, am facing this issue A resource with the ID already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State.

Can anyone help me how do i resolve this issue with terraform -refresh-only command.

Comment: If the resource already existed in the cloud infrastructure. We need to Import that resource into your already existing state file using the command Terraform Import. So that the already existing resource provisioned outside terraform will get imported to the current infrastructure plan in the state file. So that this error can be eliminated.

Comment: Yes my resource is in cloud infrastructure and also in my code. But missing in state file. Do you mean this terraform import should be used and not refresh-only.? Any refresh and example how to use it.

Comment: we can use terraform import for this case. Please provide the Terraform code along with the information of resources you provision outside of Terraform. Will demonstrate with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Most Terraform providers are designed to allow multiple independent Terraform configurations (or other infrastructure not managed by Terraform at all) to coexist in the same account, and so Terraform will typically assume that anything that wasn't created by running `terraform apply` in the current configuration is "out of bounds" for other actions on that configuration.

In your case it seems that you've created a new object outside of Terraform and so Terraform doesn't consider itself to be the owner of that object. When you declare a new object with the same configuration, Terraform thinks you intend to create a new object, and then that fails because it conflicts with an existing object that is, as far as Terraform's concerned, managed by some other system and out of bounds for the current Terraform configuration.

You can override Terraform's default assumption that you want to create any newly-declared resource by including an [`import` block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) alongside your `resource` block, like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  # (configuration matching the existing object)
}

import {
  id = "i-abc123" # Set this to the ID of the existing object
  to = aws_instance.example
}
```

If Terraform sees that there is no remote object already bound to the address `aws_instance.example` and that there *is* an `import` block referring to that address then it will ask the relevant provider to try to find an existing object matching the given `id`. If successful, Terraform will propose to adopt the existing object as being managed by this resource block, rather than proposing to create a new one.

I've used [`aws_instance`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance) from the `hashicorp/aws` provider as an example here because you didn't mention a specific resource type you are working with. The documentation for each resource type that can support import should include a section like [the "Import" section for `aws_instance`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#import) which describes what syntax of string value should be assigned to the `id` argument for that resource type.

The possibility of `import` blocks in the configuration is relatively new and so some providers might only document the usage of the `terraform import` imperative command. In current versions of Terraform at the time of writing, you can assume that the `id` argument in an `import` block expects the same string syntax as would be used in the second argument to `terraform import`; these are just two different ways to access the same provider functionality.